# If/else nesting is skipped and goes to the next else statement

Tags: java

In my if/else statement I have two if/else statement and two nested if/else statement. When I run the program and input "s" it would skip the first if statement and then jump to the second if statement and jump back to the while loop and never reaches the nested if/else statement. Now what I intended the program to do is when I input "s" and it runs through the first if statement, in theory, it should run through the nested else statement and the output would be "You can't go that way". The program works when I input the correct input "n". Any suggestions?

```
while(!input.equals("quit")) {
     System.out.println(map.rooms[row][col].name);
     System.out.print("<");
     input = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();
     if (input.equals("n")) {      
         if (map.rooms[row][col].isValidExit("n"))
             row--;
         else
             System.out.println("There is no exit that way");
     } else if (input.equals("e")) {
         if (map.rooms[row][col].isValidExit("e"))
             row++;
         else
             System.out.println("There is no exit that way");
     }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to add blocks for `else if (input.equals("w"))` and `else if (input.equals("s"))`?

Comment: Should that that `row++` shouldn't be `col++`? or should that e be an s? because it appears that when your user wants to east he goes down

Comment: @vandale yes that is correct I forgot to change that in my syntax. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's clear that the program will never reach the nested if/else statement when your input is 's' because your main if else statement is just processing the 'n' case and the 'e' case , if want it to process other cases and show the message "There is no exit that way" , then your code should be like this :

```
while(!input.equals("quit")) {
 System.out.println(map.rooms[row][col].name);
 System.out.print("<");
 input = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();
 if (input.equals("n")) {      
     if (map.rooms[row][col].isValidExit("n"))
         row--;
     else
         System.out.println("There is no exit that way");
 } else if (input.equals("e")) {
     if (map.rooms[row][col].isValidExit("e"))
         row++;
     else
         System.out.println("There is no exit that way");
 }
 else
 {
     // you should process other cases here like "s"
     System.out.println("There is no exit that way");
 }
}
```

Comment: I thought what you showed me fixed the issue but after testing it, it's missing the point of the nested else statement. I want it to run through the first if and when it is not "n" i want it to run the nested if/else statement which should print out "there is no exit that way".

Comment: in your code you're not allowing this because when it is not 'n' it will check if it is 'e' and then it will never check anything else like 's' , that's why I suggested creating another else for other states , look for the update of my answer.

Comment: maybe if you change "e" to "s" , it will work correctly , if this is the case the answer to your question will be the answer below .

Comment: I understand. Even though I add other process as you mentioned, it does not fix the issue. I created the nested if/else statement so that I will not get a NullPointerException. This is a 2-D array containing 4x4 cells. Not all cells are filled. So when I do the process you tell me, it does in a way fix the issue but not entirely. The reason why is because when you start off in the program, to the right or "e" has no cell. So at the start if you input "e" you will get a nullpointerexception error. Is there a way to structure it so I can validate my exits?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding how conditional branches work.

When you say

```
if (input.equals("n")
{
    System.out.println("go north");
}  
else if (input.equals("e")
{
    System.out.println("go east");
}
```

It will check if the input equals n or not, and if not, it will check the next branch. It *will not* go into the branch even if it evaluates to false, because otherwise what would be the point of the conditional branch in the first place? You might as well take it out.

I don't think your "intended" logic would make sense either: if a user hits "s", why would the program check whether north is passable? Your design doesn't seem to make sense from a player's perspective.

If you want to have a case for "s", you can just add it as another branch for when the user does enter "s"

```
else if (input.equals("s"))
{
    System.out.println("go south");
}
```